# Get all images from any url in php?

Tags: php

I have input type text for url on my website. By posting value of this url field, i want to fetch all possible images (if present) from that particular url as this happens in http://facebook.com at update status textarea. So what will be the code for this in php?

Thanks.

Comment: any reason for devoting this clear and challenging question? I think no one is superior to answer this challenging question.

Comment: Tthe reason that this post has been down voted is you have not given any indication that you have even attempted to try and do this yourself. If you have a specific problem with some peice of code, post it, but dont expect the community to help you with a whole section of code. To start you off, you should look to use the cUrl and regex functions of PHP. Also, people might be more willing to help when you have proven yourself in the community (reputation) and not just joined to ask someone to provide you code.

Comment: fetch the html from the url and use html/dom parser

Comment: @MichaelH This is not solution of my question.

Comment: I answered your question in the comment. Im not providing you the answer, but simply stating the place you should start looking is cUrl and Regex.

Comment: It is better to ask questions that would provide answers as to where to start opposed to questions that are more along the lines of "can you code this for me?"

Comment: Please do not create different accounts to ask the same question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479014/fetch-all-images-from-url-in-php-as-it-happens-in-facebook-com

Comment: I challenge you to do my job for me. Who of you is man (or woman) enough to do it? I challenge you.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook has the OpenGraph protocol.  A lot of sites that you will link on Facebook will not render an image.  This is because there is no configuration with `og` tags.  There would be a very large amount of code required to really achieve any significant results of your crawled images.

There are many images that just aren't meant to be used that way such as spacer images, tracking images, etc...  When you pull all image tags from a site you will get a number of these images that are mostly just dead space.

As always, there are multiple ways to approach this problem.  They all begin with obtaining the source of the url.  [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) is my preferred method to achieve this.

From there you need to parse the information in the source to find the source of the images.  This can be done with [regular expressions (regex)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html) or my preferred method is to use the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) Class in PHP.

A brief example as to how to approach obtaining the source url from the image tags using the DOMDocument class is as follows:

```
// Load your HTML result into $response prior to here.
// Additionally, ensure that you have the root url for the
//     page loaded into $base_url.
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($response);

$images = array();

// For all found img tags
foreach($document->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    // Extract what we want
    $image = array(
        // Here we take the img tag, get the src attribute
        //     we then run it through a function to ensure that it is not a
        //     relative url.
        // The make_absolute() function will not be covered in this snippet.
        'src' => make_absolute($img->getAttribute('src'), $base_url),
    );

    // Skip images without src
    if( ! $image['src'])
        continue;

    // Add to collection. Use src as key to prevent duplicates.
    $images[$image['src']] = $image;
}
```